# ServiceStack View/Template control when exception occurs?

Tags: templates, view, exception, servicestack

I added some razor views and use a request filter to check browser version and switch between desktop and mobile views.  But when a exception occurs, especially validation exception, it seems the framework return immediately and never touched any custom code.  I tried request/response filter, service exception handler, none got executed.  It seems to ignore view/template specified in URL query string as well.

Is there way to set view/template during exception?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first question is how are you handling validation exceptions?

the most common procedure to perform this kind of task is by using the fluentValidation, the response can return a message for more than one validation at the time, all the validations are against DTOs and you´ll need to implement an AbstractValidator, the first thing you need to do is to register the validators that belons to your applciation like the following:

```
Plugins.Add(new ValidationFeature());
container.RegisterValidators(typeof(CredentialsAuthValidator).Assembly);
```

I´m valdiating in this case that the Auth username and password should not be Empty, take a look to the following example:

```
public class CredentialsAuthValidator : AbstractValidator<ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.Auth>
    {
        public CredentialsAuthValidator()
        {
            RuleSet(ApplyTo.Post, () =>
                {
                    RuleFor(x => x.UserName).NotNull().WithMessage("Username Required").When(x => x.provider == "Credentials");
                    RuleFor(x => x.Password).NotNull().WithMessage("Password Required").When(x => x.provider == "Credentials");
                }
                );
        }
    }
```

if some of the validation fails you´ll get a responseStatus from the server with the errorCode and the messages.

You can configure a custom httpHandlers in the case you would like to have a handler for specific scenarios or a global error handler, this can be performed in your serviceHost configuration, something like this:

```
 GlobalHtmlErrorHttpHandler = new RazorHandler("/views/error"),
 CustomHttpHandlers =
                            {
                                {HttpStatusCode.NotFound, new RazorHandler("/views/notfound")},
                                {HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, new RazorHandler("/views/login")},
                                {HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, new RazorHandler("/views/forbidden")},
                            }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I think I found the root of my problem.  I'll write up a summary soon.

Comment: Thanks again.  Still couldn't figure out the view switching during exception.  But settled for a single error page that works in both view.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help from Pedro, and especially mythz from ServiceStack.  Now I think I start to understand my problems.

ServiceStack is first and foremost a service framework and Razor is just another view over the same result.  But I was a little hesitate with a full on client side solution and keep falling back to familiar territory and looking for some kind of code-behind feature.  That seems to be the root of lots of my struggles.

After some more research, this is what I come up so far.

- ServiceStack for service, of course.
- Razor view to build the basic layout and the main page for each major feature
- Build a json script tag from model to hold initial data, like in SS's HTML Report
- Jquery and Eldarion ajax for all subsequent in-page processing
- Handlebars for javascript templating
- Verifyjs for validation

So far look promising.  Pages are lot smaller in size, running super smooth and mostly pure json flying over the wire.

Still a work in progress, all suggestions welcome.

Comment: Turned out I was a little too optimistic.  Unless go for single page approach, otherwise, it's hard to keep track states once navigate away from current page.  Even harder to reconcile between desktop browser and Jquery mobile.  Keeping most of the stuff, but limiting client side template to local manipulation only.

Comment: Have you considered servicestak for rest services + Razor (for some security reasons) + angularJS in the client site, that works like a charm! keep going with SS you won´t regret!

Comment: Thanks.  I'll look into it.  During my initial 5 minutes attemp over other client side framework, I Was a little scared about all the client side model, binding and the lack of intellisense

Comment: yeah it´s scary for the first time trying seeing the mv* pattern in the client side but! you get use to it and the double binding is painless straight fordward, for the intellisense do you have resharper?

Answer (score 0):

ViewSwitch works when I changed to use Request Filter instead.  Got the correct layout and all the references, etc.  Although they have to share the same error page, but there's not much formatting in there.